# Select :first-child by attr name

Tags: jquery

I wonder how to select first of element by giving attr ?

**Example :**

```
<div data-name>
    <span></span>
    <span data-sub-name>1</span>
    <span data-sub-name>2</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('[data-name] > [data-sub-name]:first-child').addClass('active');
```

It doesnt work when some element before `[data-sub-name]`

What I am missing ?

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/7cn1ymq4/

Edit : Should work if multiple groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:first` instead of `:first-child`

```
$('[data-name] > [data-sub-name]:first').addClass('active');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nLjvfkrm/2/)

If you have multiple groups of elements, you would need to loop through each one:

```
$('[data-name]').each(function() {
    $(this).find('[data-sub-name]:first').addClass('active');
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/7cn1ymq4/2/)

Comment: Not posible without `each` func. ?

Comment: Add it @MohitArora for another way

Answer (score 2):

try this:-

```
$('[data-name]').find('[data-sub-name]:first').addClass('active');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/7cn1ymq4/4/)

Comment: this is another variant, `OP` is talking about `:first-child` is right selector then how won't work with `[attribute]` selector like `[attribute]:first-child`

Comment: @Girish `:first-child` Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent. if  he remove `<span></span>` from div then it will also work fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use [first](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
$('[data-name] > [data-sub-name]').first().addClass('active');
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cn1ymq4/3/)

---

For multiple groups as per your updated question:

```
$('[data-name]').each(function(){
  $('>[data-sub-name]',this).first().addClass('active');
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cn1ymq4/6/)